# Using a if/else condition in a Cloud Firestore query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've written these scripts to run a function conditioned on the values of an `HTTP` `GET` request. The `history` var is defined correctly when I run two tests on the page:

1. `history == 0`
2. `history == 1`

The problem is allMessage function will always run, whether the value is `0` or `1`.

If I try to reverse the function (`limitMessage()` on the `if` branch, `allMessage()` on the `else` branch) `limitMessage()` is the one that runs. I have no idea why the `if else` condition doesn't work as expected.

```js
//*if else condition*

var history = "<? php echo isset($_GET['history']) ? $_GET['history'] : 0; ?>";
if (history != 1) {
  allMessage();
} else {
  limitMessage();
}

//*limitMessage*

function limitMessage() {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(doc)
    .collection(collection)
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .limit(10)
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot
        .docChanges()
        .reverse()
        .forEach(function (change) {
          var data = {
            id: change.doc.id,
            a: change.doc.data().a,
            b: change.doc.data().b,
            c: change.doc.data().c,
            d: change.doc.data().d,
            e: change.doc.data().e,
            f: change.doc.data().f,
          };

          if (change.type === "added") {
            msgData(data);
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            msgData(data);
          }
        });
    });
}

//*allMessage*

function allMessage() {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(doc)
    .collection(collection)
    .orderBy("time", "asc")
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
        var data = {
          id: change.doc.id,
          a: change.doc.data().a,
          b: change.doc.data().b,
          c: change.doc.data().c,
          d: change.doc.data().d,
          e: change.doc.data().e,
          f: change.doc.data().f,
        };

        if (change.type === "added") {
          msgData(data);
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
          msgData(data);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to check the output of `var` by using `typeof`.

You can then decide how to manage the if/else statement.

You might not be handling the output correctly and why it is always running, whether the value is 0 or 1.

```js
console.log(typeof 'checkme');
// expected output: "string"

console.log(typeof 12);
// expected output: "number"

console.log(typeof undeclaredVariable);
// expected output: "undefined"

console.log(typeof true);
// expected output: "boolean"
```

It can be confusing to write good if/else statements. To make it easier, I use `if` as `equal to` rather than `not equal` as I find it more intuitive when reading code and spotting issues.

```
var history=1;
if (history == 1) {
    console.log("yes");
} else {
    console.log("no");
}
```

Here are some of the comparison operators to try:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+
| ==        | equal to                          | 5 == 8    | false   |
|           |                                   | 5 == 5    | true    |
|           |                                   | 5 == "5"  | true    |
| ===       | equal value and equal type        | 5 === 5   | true    |
|           |                                   | 5 === "5" | false   |
| !=        | not equal                         | 5 != 8    | true    |
| !==       | not equal value or not equal type | 5 !== 5   | false   |
|           |                                   | 5 !== "5" | true    |
|           |                                   | 5 !== 8   | true    |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: im handling the output correctly, i already check on console.log and on the code. But the 
problem is the only firestore function that will run always a function that is in the if statement, even though the conditions in the if statement are false. The function that is in the else statement wont run wheter the condition is meet or not.

Comment: Do you have an example of both of your `allMessage()` and `limitMessage()`. At the moment I can only see two `allMessages()`

Comment: my bad, the code is fixed now, all message > without limit() func, order by asc, limit message > with limit(), order by desc

Comment: what i mean is, i correct the typo on that code. the problem is still there..